# bash if to check tc dev is exists

Tags: bash

I don't know about bash, but I need to check if dev enp8s0.100 exists or not
but if exists then tc qdisc del dev enp8s0.100  root otherwise just tc qdisc add dev enp8s0.100  root handle 1:0 htb default 2`

```
tc qdisc del dev enp8s0.100  root
tc qdisc add dev enp8s0.100  root handle 1:0 htb default 2

RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Note that `tc` is not part of bash itself; it's a Linux-specific tool, provided by the operating system. I'd generally suggest tagging the question Linux.

Comment: ...for that matter, it's quite possible that the best way to check if the device is configured in qdisc involves inspecting sysfs, which is *very* Linux-specific; would need to find the docs for the relevant kernel interfaces to determine if that's the case here.